# mPdf - undeclared property ktForms

Tags: php, mpdf

I have got an error when using mPdf library :

```
Cannot read an undeclared property Mpdf\Mpdf::$ktForms
vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Form.php (line 1197)
```

Context:
Symfony 3.4
Mpdf 8.0.5

Comment: What is your question? No, seriously, this is an obvious bug in the library, just fill the bugreport the way it should be filled.

Comment: @Meloman I know, I wrote it. But the undefined property is being called from mPDF code itself, hence, a bug.

Comment: Because your answer has no relation to this particular "question" or problem in general.

Comment: OK, the error message is the same, for sure. But it cannot be solved in "userland" the way your answer solves it.

Comment: the vote is not to confirm the resolution but if the answer is useful for another user. And as I said, google could bring other people on the same question for the same problem as me. anyway, I'll delete all.